# How to retrieve an item from a List in android?

Tags: java, android, list

How to retrieve items from a List?

```
List<String> strings;
```

Using Java (in an Android App) I have tried using strings.get(0) but this crashes the app. It launches a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: And what is the crash? Did you initialize your list? Did you put Strings in it?

Comment: List<String>strings; . You need to initialize the list.. Otherwise you will get NullPointerException

Comment: Show us how you initialize the list.

Comment: List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("string1", "string2", "string2");

Comment: :)) java is not different in Android, it does not have a different behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the list.

```
List<String> strings=new ArrayList<String>();
```

And then add values and get values from list.

Answer (score 0):

You can't retrieve any element from that list unless you initialize it,

This line means a reference without a real location on memory.

```
List<String>strings;
```

You need to do:

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Then you can use the list function by adding and getting elements from it.

Answer (score 0):

you initialize it first

```
List<String> strings=new ArrayList<String>();
```

then populate it like

```
strings.add("hello");
```

then access the value

Answer (score 0):

You can use this syntaxe :

```
List<String> strings=new List<String>();
strings.add("mystring");
for (String elem : strings) {
        Log.d("My String",elem);
    }
```